# Bootstrap datepicker date validation

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker

When I enter (change) manually date inside input field and then clicked outside the input field the date value is empty if format not correct.

I've been trying to trigger enter event when clicked outside the input field which should then the datepicker validate the date.

My code:

```
$('#js-filter-input-date-from').change(function (e) {
    if (this.value === '')
    {
        var e = $.Event("keypress");
        e.keyCode = 13; // # Some key code value

        $('#js-filter-input-date-from').trigger(e);
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) event.

So, when the input lose focus, you trigger the datepicker to validate.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using Blur

```
<input id="myDate" (blur)="setDateOnBlur($event)">    

setDateOnBlur(elem) {
    $(elem.target).datepicker().trigger('changeDate');  
}

$('#myDate').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-M-yyyy'
});

$('#myDate').on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    var Date = ev.format ? ev.format("dd-M-yyyy") : $('#myDate').val();
});
```